# Get the number of rows between timestamps as a list

Tags: mysql, sql, ignite

I have a sql database table called Table with following columns. As in the image I would like to get the count between each timestamps.
[image: This Image]

From this command

```
Select count(*)
from Table
where orderId=500
and (timestamp<=t1 and timestamp>=t2)
or (timestamp<=t3 and timestamp>=t4);
```

I was able to get the total count between timestamps. I was wondering how to get the count between each timestamp condition as a list.

Comment: Can you share what your expected output would look like?

Comment: And the query with the variables described with values

Comment: Provide your timestamps as a rowset (subquery, for example) into the query, not as values.

Comment: my expected out put is the count as a list. As with the image, expected out put is [4 3 1 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for conditional aggregation?

```
Select sum(timestamp <= t1 and timestamp >= t2),
       sum(timestamp <= t3 and timestamp >= t4)
from Table
where orderId = 500;
```

Note:  The above is syntax specific to MySQL.  The more general syntax is:

```
Select sum(case when timestamp <= t1 and timestamp >= t2 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when timestamp <= t3 and timestamp >= t4 then 1 else 0 end)
from Table
where orderId = 500;
```